azure-pipelines.yml cannot find global.json
I cannot seem to get my Azure Pipeline to install dotnet as defined in my global.json file. It keeps failing with the following error.

##[error]Failed to find global.json at and inside path: /Users/runner/work/1/s

I have a root repository akin to the following
- azure-pipelines.yml
- build.sh
- global.json
- myapp.sln
- /src
- /tests

Now in my azure-pipelines.yml I'm trying to have it install the dotnet version from my global.json using the following task.
stages:
  - stage: macOS_latest
    displayName: 'macOS-latest'
    dependsOn: [  ]
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    jobs:
      - job: Run
        displayName: 'Build, Test, and Release Artifacts'
        dependsOn: [  ]
        steps:
          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: 'Use .NET global'
            inputs:
              packageType: sdk
              useGlobalJson: true
              workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              installationPath: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet'

and my global.json is simple
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "8.0.401",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}


With same file structure and yaml, the task works fine on my side.

As per the error: ##[error]Failed to find global.json at and inside path: /Users/runner/work/1/s, please check if you are checking out correct branch in the pipeline, make sure it has the json file.
When you run the pipeline, make sure correct branch is chosen.

In addition, you can add below task ahead to confirm the file list and current directory:
          - bash: |
             ls 
             pwd


If you have repository resource, or template in your real yaml, you need to confirm the real code checked out.
Edit:
As per your bash task output, there's no source code before the dotnet task. Please add checkout task before dotnet task, make sure it can find the global.json file.

For me, it's part of a pull request to get it merged into 'main'

Do you trigger the pipeline after PR merge(It's CI trigger), or during pull request exists(It's PR trigger)? PR trigger pipeline are checking out dummy repo {repo}@refs/pull/{pullrequestid}/merge not target main. If you don't have the global.json on the dummy repo, pipeline cannot find the file. Make sure you have global.json in source branch so that the file exists in dummy repo. If the issue persists, please add more details about the pipeline yaml.

global.json has been in main for over a year, nothing has changed there. The current branch was taken off of main

Interesting This is my output from running the bash line: /bin/bash /Users/runner/work/_temp/11c8e483-8632-4c62-b093-d5291b097f91.sh
/Users/runner/work/1/s

well shit. I had to put the checkout script before the dotnet install bit

Typically the checkout will be automatically injected into pipeline, but if you have other checkout it could skip. As per the bash task output, you don't have the source code. Yes, please add checkout before dotnet install, make sure it has the global.json to use. I edited the answer as well.

@ChaseFlorell, may i know if the answer helps? and is there still any query? glad to help!
